# Flattening the nested Objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, typescript

The original idea behind the problem is that the API I'm working with returns one type of a response for `GET`, and requires another type to do `POST` / `PUT`. The object I'm receiving from the `GET` has a format like this:

```
 const rawObject = {
  data1: {
    id: 1,
    value: 444
  },
  data2: null
 }
```

In order to be able to update it, or do a `POST` request to create a new one, I had to convert it into this format (This is the final output of my solution as well):

```
const convertedObject = {
  data1: 444,
  data2: null
};
```

The object I'm converting consists of another objects within it (One level max - as in the first example) or **null**. If the object is not null, I only care about the `value` of a nested object, therefore I flatten it as - `data1: 444`.

The solution I came up with is this (It works perfectly):

```
const rawObject = {
  data1: {
    id: 1,
    value: 444
  },
  data2: null
}

let convertedObject: any = {};

Object.entries(rawObject).map((item: any) => {
  const rawObjectKey = item[0];
  const rawObjectValue = item[1];
  if (rawObjectValue) {
    convertedObject = {...convertedObject, ...{[rawObjectKey]: rawObjectValue.value}};
    return;
  }
  convertedObject = {...convertedObject, ...{[rawObjectKey]: null}};
  return;
});
console.log(convertedObject); // Check the Output in example above
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-3agbqj?file=index.js)

I decided to use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) as I need both key:value pairs available. The if check I'm doing is there because object could have null value, therefore `rawObjectValue` would be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Review

- Your final `return` statement is redundant.
- The use of `const` is correct here (`rawObjectKey`, `rawObjectValue`) because you only assign these variables once. Many developers tend to use `let` or `var` here incorrectly.
- Your method is a bit convoluted with those almost-equal code blocks. `convertedObject = {...convertedObject, ...`

---

### Alternative

You could write this more compact, DRY and using built-in function `reduce`. We start with an empty object `{}` and inject each entry with the flattened data to obtain the result.

```
 const convertedObject = Object.entries(rawObject).reduce(
  (acc, item) => { 
    acc[item[0]] = item[1] != null ? item[1].value : null;
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

---

### Future Releases

There is a thing called [*optional chaining*](https://medium.com/bsadd/optional-chaining-in-react-native-805a374788d3) aka [*null propagation*](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/null-propagation-operator) aka [the Elvis operator](https://www.beyondjava.net/elvis-operator-aka-safe-navigation-javascript-typescript). It's not standard Typescript (yet?), but is already supported in [babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining).

This is a feature request to track. If ever implemented, it would allow us to call something like `item[1]?.value:null` instead of `item[1] != null ? item[1].value : null`.